# Trying to move my selected listItem to the top of a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecyclerView Adapter is getting a bit busy. This is what I'm trying to do but with no success so far. When the user clicks on the popup menu, if the match isn't the currently active one they will be presented with 2 options (edit, delete). When the user selects edit, I'm making this the current match but I also want to move it to the top of the recyclerview. I have attempted this:

Collections.swap(mMatches, 0, position);
notifyItemMoved(position, 0);

but with no success. What can I do? The code is below:

```
public class MatchItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Match> mMatches;
    private final Context mContext;

    public MatchItemAdapter(Context context, List<Match> items) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMatches = items;
    }

    @Override
    public MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_match, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MatchItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Match match = mMatches.get(position);
        holder.matchIsActive = false;
        final Match globalMatch = GlobalMatch.getMatch();

        try {
            holder.tvName.setText(match.getMatchName());
            holder.tvDate.setText(match.getMatchDate());
            holder.imageView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.hiddenMatchId.setText(match.getMatchId());
            holder.container.findViewById(R.id.list_item_container);


            Typeface bold = Typeface.create("san-serif", Typeface.BOLD);

            String itemMatchId = holder.hiddenMatchId.getText().toString();

            if (itemMatchId.equals(globalMatch.getMatchId())) {
                holder.tvName.setTypeface(bold);
                holder.container.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a4a4a4"));
                holder.tvName.setTextSize(24);
                holder.matchIsActive = true;

            }

            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {

                    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), holder.imageView);
                    if (!holder.matchIsActive) {
                        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.edit_match:

                                        GlobalMatch.changeMatch(match); // make this match the current match

                                        // place a string representation of the current match in SharedPreferences
                                        String jsonString = MatchHelper.jsonStringFromMatch(holder.imageView.getContext(), match);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = holder.itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                                                MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, holder.itemView.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                        editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH, jsonString);
                                        editor.apply();

                                        // place this match at the top of the list
                                        Collections.swap(mMatches, 0, position);
                                        notifyItemMoved(position, 0);



                                        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), EditMatchActivity.class);
                                        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
                                    case R.id.delete_match:

                                        mMatches.remove(match);
                                        notifyItemRemoved(position);

                                        // delete file from internal storage
                                        File dir = holder.itemView.getContext().getFilesDir();
                                        File file = new File(dir, "match." + match.getMatchId() + ".json");
                                        boolean deleted = file.delete();
                                        Log.d("TAG", "The file was deleted");

                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    } else {

                        // If the current item is selected and you click on the side menu -> don't show delete
                        // delete isn't an option for active Matches
                        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_no_delete, popup.getMenu());
                        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                    case R.id.edit_match:

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), EditMatchActivity.class);
                                        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                        break;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //displaying the popup menus
                    popup.show();
                }
            });

            holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    holder.matchIsActive = true;   // maybe this is redundant
                    String jsonString = MatchHelper.jsonStringFromMatch(holder.imageView.getContext(), match);

                    GlobalMatch.changeMatch(match);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = holder.itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences(
                            MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, holder.itemView.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH, jsonString);
                    editor.apply();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMatches.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDate;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView hiddenMatchId;
        public View container;

        boolean matchIsActive = false;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_name);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_date);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            hiddenMatchId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_id_hidden);
            container = (View) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_container);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the code with this and it worked:

```
Collections.swap(mMatches,holder.getAdapterPosition() ,0 );  
mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If It didn't work, try using `notifyDataSetChanged()` after swapping data as the last resort.

Comment: Have you tried delete and insert? According to your question, it should not be a swap operation.

Comment: delete works for me. But in my case when I want to edit the listItem I click in edit. From there it brings me to another screen. After I've edited the list item and I go back to the previous screen, I want that item to be listed at the top of the recyclerview now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's wrong with the code that cause the RecyclerView not updated its items. But from you code as shown below

```
Collections.swap(mMatches, 0, position);
notifyItemMoved(position, 0);
```

I found that, by swap two items in collection, you should move two items, not just one.
That is, for example, the original list is [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], swap(list, 0, 3) will get [3, 1, 2, 0, 4]. Therefore you need:

```
notifyItemMoved(position, 0); 
notifyItemMoved(1, position);
```

Comment: using this implementation (outside Activity calling this Adapter class) how do I get a reference to the Recyclerview that is calling this Adapter from within the Adapter class itself?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?